# Kotlin hardcoded String

Tags: java, android, kotlin, multilingual

I want to add multilingual support to my app using the Android Studio Translations editor. But it only supports .xml strings. I have some strings in data class and I use data class for making ArrayList. I really want to call these strings from .xml but I couldn't figure out how.

my data class:

```
data class Infodc (
        val id: Int,
        val header: String,
        val image: Int,
        val infoOne: String,
        val infoTwo: String
)
```

my list

```
object Constants{
    fun getInfo(): ArrayList<Infodc>{
        val infoList = ArrayList<Infodc>()

        val inf1 = Infodc(
            1, "header_str", R.drawable.image0,
            "string_1", "string_2")
        infoList.add(inf1)
        return infoList
    }
}
```

I tried `R.string.string_header` for `header = "header_str"` but that only show 10 digits, not the string itself.

After that, I tried `getString` but again I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val infodc = Infodc(
            1,
            R.string.header,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
            R.string.info_one,
            R.string.info_two,
            this
        )

        Log.d("MyTag", "$infodc") // D/MyTag: Infodc(id=1, header=Header, image=2131099744, infoOne=Info One, infoTwo=Info Two)


    }
}

data class Infodc(
    val id: Int,
    val header: String,
    val image: Int,
    val infoOne: String,
    val infoTwo: String
)
{
    constructor(
        id: Int,
        @StringRes header: Int,
        @DrawableRes image: Int,
        @StringRes infoOne: Int,
        @StringRes infoTwo: Int,
        context: Context
    ) : this(
        id,
        context.getString(header),
        image,
        context.getString(infoOne),
        context.getString(infoTwo)
    )
}
```

Now You can pass to a constructor id of String and image but as a class field You will get String

---

Another way is to have a class that only contains an id of string and then when You want to use it use `getString` of that field.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is working. I want to ask `) : this(` is it an id or is it coming from `context: Context` ?

Comment: I don't understand :/ `: this` is calling a constructor and You pass `context` to be able to get String from the application